# Merge ICollection of same type to return combined in single property

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

I have ICollection's of the same type

```
ICollection<Food> Fruits{get; set;}
ICollection<Food> Vegetable{get; set;}
ICollection<Food> IceCream{get; set;}
```

These first two are automapped I want to add an AllFood that essentially looks like

```
ICollection<Food> AllFood
{
   get
   {
      return Fruits.Concat(Vegetable).Concat(IceCream);
   }   
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how this should work - I've tried a few different ways - this particular way produces a message

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection' An explicit conversion exists are you missing a cast.

I should mention that there is potential for these items to be 'null'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Concat() returns an IEnumerable, not and ICollection. To deal with the null problem, consider doing (this.Fruits ?? Enumerable.Empty()).Concat...

If you change the property type to IEnumerable it will work, but you won't be able to add to the collection using AllFood.Add().

You could also return this.Fruits.Concat(this.Vegetable)....ToList() which would return ICollection. However, this would create a new copy of the list on every call.

If you want to be able to add new objects directly to AllFood, then you'll need to implement a custom collection type.